# Вставить слово "нет" вместо каждого третьего пробела без использования string.h

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Не могу понять в чем проблема,программа выдает ошибку на моменте копирования буквы "н"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int count=0,i,k=0,u=0,l;
char new_arr[256],arr[256],beg[5]="нет ";
gets(arr);
for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
{if (arr[i]==' ')
{count++;}
if(count==3)
{
    while(u<=i)
    {new_arr[u]=arr[u];
    u++;    
    }
    new_arr[u+1]=beg[0];
    new_arr[u+2]=beg[1];
    new_arr[u+3]=beg[2];
    new_arr[u+4]=beg[3];    
   count=0;
}
}
printf("\n%i",u);
printf("\n%s",new_arr);
}
```

Comment: Просто скажите - вот как вы представляете, как должен действовать человек, прочитавший ваш вопрос? Компилировать и тестировать, пытаясь понять - при каких данных, в какой строке, что за ошибка?... Или достать хрустальный шар и смотреть в него, пытаясь понять? :) Нет, ну вот я вас спрошу - проблема с телевизором. И даже покажу фото выключенного телика. И даже - проблема при включении. Ваши действия? Как вы будете мне помогать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, примерно так, если в новую строку (и не проверять, что точно хватит места).

```
int main()
{
    char new_arr[512],arr[256],beg[5]="нет ";
    gets_s(arr,256);
    int u = 0;
    for(int i = 0, count = 0; i < strlen(arr); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == ' ' && ++count%3 == 0)
        {
            new_arr[u++]=beg[0];
            new_arr[u++]=beg[1];
            new_arr[u++]=beg[2];
            new_arr[u++]=beg[3];
        }
        else new_arr[u++] = arr[i];
    }
    new_arr[u] = 0;
    printf("\n%s",new_arr);
}
```